# fractions with SI units package

Tags: siunitx

Hey I'm trying to display the fraction of:
[image]

But I'm not sure how to do it with the `siunitx` package.
This is what I got so far:
`\SI[quotient-mode=fraction]{16 2/3}{\metre\per\second}`
But the result is not correct:
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: What do mean with $16\,\dfrac23$? $16+\dfrac23$ or $16\cdot\dfrac23$?

Comment: `16+\frac23`, I guess.

Comment: I find that notation really confusing  (saw first time when my daughter was at a school in Colorado, US). For me $16\frac{2}{3}$ has been $\frac{32}{3}$ since ever...

Comment: @Rmano Yea it's the notation I was taught in school as-well, but it's not a made up notation by schools, even some scientific calculators support defining fractions with 3 variables where the first one will be `16` in this example as in `16+\frac23`

Comment: @Rmano https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction#Mixed_numbers

Comment: @ivankokan thanks for thr link! I assure you that, at least in Italy and Spain, that mixed fraction form is never used not taught... Multiplication is always assumed. That's worse than date format :-;!

Comment: It is a common thing in Croatia. Of course, it is used only when explicit numbers are in case, it is not used for any symbolic form (i.e. it is not used - maybe even forbidden - for `a b/c` as this is much easier to misunderstand).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parser in `siunitx` does not attempt to 'read' fractions in the way you want: it ignores spaces so parses as `162/3`. If you want manual formatting, you'll need to turn off the parser

```latex
\SI[quotient-mode=fraction,parse-numbers=false]{16\frac{2}{3}}{\metre\per\second}
```

Comment: You can't actually _measure_ thirds or whatever, only `0.666...` to some precision ...

Comment: You can't actually measure `2` either. Only `2.000…` (or `1.999…`) to some precision. 